# How do I get a nested query to only display content that the main query outputed

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, query

I have a CPT 'artists' and a CPT 'events' I want the 'artists' to query first based off the posts tag and then I want the 'events' to query events based off what 'artists' was queried.

Heres what I got so far ::

```
<?php
$artist_id   = $tags[0]->term_id;
$artist_id1  = $tags[1]->term_id;
$artist_id2  = $tags[2]->term_id;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'tag__in'   => array( $artist_id, $artist_id1, $artist_id2 ),
);
$m_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($m_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($m_query->have_posts()) :
        $m_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'col-4-img-thumb' ); ?>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?><h3></a>       
        <?php
        $eventarg = array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'tag__in' => array($m_query),
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $eventarg );
        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
                $my_query->the_post();
                $titlesub = get_the_title();
                echo substr( $titlesub, 0, -10); 
                ?>
                <br>     
                <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: proper code indentation makes debugging much easier.

Comment: I cleaned it up a little bit